# Chrome Extension doesn't open when clicked icon (developer mode)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wanted to develop new Chrome extension, but I don't have any practice about it. I just create simple extension file as "Hello World", but when I uploaded it to toolbar, it doesn't open. I dont know whats wrong. I don't get any error from `chrome://extensions`. I can't find anything for this problem. Thanks!
This is my `manifest.json` file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Hello World Demo",
  "description": "A hello world extension!",
  "version": "1.0",
  "icons": {
  "128": "icon128.png",
  "48": "icon48.png",
  "16": "icon16.png"
  },

"browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon16.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
 }
}
```

this is my `popup.html` file:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Hello World</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h2 id="greet">Hello World!</h2>
      <input id="name" type="text"/>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure the path to your popup.html file is correct?

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided does not seem to have any errors. When I create a new local unpacked extension with your code everything seems to be working as expected.

[image]

Are you sure that all the icons listed in your manifest exist and that the path to your `popup.html` file is correct? If Chrome has any problems loading your manifest, it should throw an error of some kind on the `chrome://extensions` page.

Comment: Yeah, i`m sure. I clicked icon 50 times, but popup.html doesn't show up.

Comment: I don't know how, but i found `"converted_from_user_script": true,` and popup.html works now.

Comment: Thanks for your try :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my folder structure of unpacked extension:

[image: This is my folder structure of unpacked extension]